# How to show 3x3 gridview of images in android

Tags: android, xml, gridview

I am taking help from this link: [Source](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_grid_view.htm) to create image gallery. I want 3x3 sized image gallery. But I dont know how to do this. Please help me.

Xml Code-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:id="@+id/gridview"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:columnWidth="90dp"
   android:numColumns="auto_fit"
   android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
   android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
   android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
   android:gravity="center"
/>
```

Activity code-

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
      gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
   }

}
```

Comment: what is wrong with your code?

Comment: @Raghunandan In that link total 15 images. And I want only 9 images.

Comment: when I use 9 images below half screen of device blank.

Comment: you need to space them properly

Comment: @Raghunandan sorry first I posted wrong link and code. please check above code.

Answer (score 1):

add following code on XML:

```
android:numColumns="3"
```

or use following code on java code:

```
gridView.setNumColumns(3);
```

if you want have fix row in your `GridView`, you need dynamically set the layout params to your `ImageView`. see [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762987/creating-gridview-with-3-rows-of-imageviews-that-fill-the-whole-screen) for getting your answer

Comment: see my Edit to get fix row number too

Comment: sorry first I posted wrong link and code. please check above code.

Comment: see my answer, this can help you.

Comment: Is it possible to set column width based on screen width?

Comment: you need do this on your code too, get width of screen and use second code for set Number column.